# "$!" is used for?

Tags: shell

While going through:

```
info coreutils 'dd invocation'
```

I came across:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=10MB & pid=$!
```

What is `$!` used for?

Comment: Are you using bash?

Comment: @slm how am I supposed to find out?

Comment: You could try this command: `echo $SHELL`

Comment: @slm yes, it's bash. `/bin/bash`.

Comment: `$!` is (at least) POSIX so not specific to `bash`.  I'd assume it's universal to `sh`.

Comment: another possible duplicate: [In UNIX shell scripting: What does $! expand to?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1672960/1309352)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're talking about Bash they're in the "Special Parameters" section of the Bash man page.

```
!      Expands to the process ID of the most recently executed background 
       (asynchronous) command.
```

#### Example

```
$ sleep 10 &
[1] 22257

$ echo $!
22257
```

#### Your command

So with this command:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=10MB & pid=$!
```

The `dd` command is backgrounded, and the resulting process ID (`$!`) is stored in a variable `pid` for use there after.

#### References

- [Bash Beginners Guide - 3.2.5. Special parameters](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html#sect_03_02_05)

Answer (score 6):

`$!` is used to get the PID(process identifier) of the most recent background command.

There is also `!$`:

`!$` is used to get last argument for the last executed command.